# gcc compiler in Cygwin output .exe

Tags: c, gcc

Just starting in C, and learning the basics.
I have created a simple program that when compiled, would expected to compile as a.out however gcc is compiling as a.exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC on Windows defaults to creating an file named `a.exe` on Windows, because the `.exe` extension is important - a file name `a.out` would not recognized as an executable program on Windows. The default output could be named `a.out.exe` but it would be different from `a.out` anyway, so it is just as sensible to produce a file named `a.exe` instead.

`a.exe` is less keypresses, too.

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought that could be the case but I was not sure.